# How to make the Github effect at loading a page with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have you seen that in github (and also in the new hotmail) the load of a new page do not need to reload all the page but only a small part of it (with left-slide effect). Also have you notice that the URL change but we are not loading from cero that page.

I guess they use something like ajax but not sure, also no idea how do they change the url of the page (it is possible with js).

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history. They also blogged about it here - https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this following tutorial for examples of working with jQuery and sliding effects. Github is also making heavy use of fadeIn effects etc. Hopefully that should point you in the right direction!

[jQuery Sliding Samples](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions)
[jQuery Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)
[jQuery fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)